# Embedding SQLite database in output exe file

Tags: c#, sqlite

I want to embed an SQLite database in my output *.exe file.
I have heard of ILMerge but as far as I know it's used only for assemblies/DLLs.
I have also seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38178979/8532902) but it's about including the DB in the output directory, while I want it to be inside the *.exe, itself.

I have added the database file to my project as an "Existing File..." and have read on the various build actions but I am not sure if I will be able to connect fine to it if I use them or what action I should use so that I can retrieve data from the DB.

Comment: Add it as a resource.

Comment: @dymanoid, add it to the project and set build action to "Content" or in a *.resx file or in another way?