How do I use System.Data.SQLite in a VSIX project?
How do I use System.Data.SQLite in a VSIX (Visual Studio extension) project?
At runtime, I get the error:

System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The specified module could not be found.

I assume SQLite.Interop.dll is not being copied to the VSIX package directory. I'm not sure the proper way to try copy it over.
I see in the ProjectName/bin/Debug/x64 or x86 folder, there's a SQLite.Interop.dll file. I tried going to source.extension.vsixmanifest > Assets > New Microsoft.VisualStudio.Assembly from File on filesystem and select that mentioned SQLite.Interop.dll file, but it always gives an error message:

VSIX Manifest Editor
Unable to get assembly name from assembly at path:
'C:\Users\name\source\repos\ProjectName\ProjectName\bin\Debug\x64
SQLite.lnterop.dll'.

I am not sure if that's the correct way to try copy it over.

The issue is similar to this one that may help.

Install "sqlite-net-pcl" nuget package

When trying to use it, I still get a runtime error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'SQLite-net, Version=1.9.172.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'. I assume there's still an issue of needed files not being copied to the VSIX directory.

which platform you are using?? Make sure to clean your project not just from inside visual studio, but also delete any debug or release folders within bin and obj folders. Then build your project again.

I'm using Visual Studio 2022, and create a new project from VSIX template. Nothing else changed except I'm trying to use SQLite. The run button indicates "Current Instance [Visual Studio Community 2022]", it runs a new instance of Visual Studio 2022 where I can test out my extension, but trying to do anything with SQLite will give me those runtime errors. I believe the VSIX extension that runs is created in a folder such as C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_e25d02beExp\Extensions\Company\ProjectName\1.0. I assume needed files aren't copied there. You can replicate.

By platform I mean that are you using console application, web application or MAUI application? You might be having compatibility issue that SQLite do not support your current platform or you  need to check the compatibility of "sqlite-net-pcl" library.

It's a VSIX Project (Visual Studio extension). For tool windows, it uses WPF. It's a Visual Studio extension that only runs as an extension inside of Visual Studio, it's not an external application.

Okay, got it. You need to check available options for VSIX publishing in order to copy the target DLL files. This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174119/how-do-i-include-my-sqlite-database-in-my-published-vb-net-project
